Conditional expectation of family of random variables parametrized by a random variable
Suppose we have a random variable $X_s$ that explicitly depends on some number $s$, seen as a parameter for instance. Now, let $Y$ be a random variable such that for every $s$, $X_s$ and $Y$ are independent. Can we then claim that $\mathbb E[X_Y | Y=s] = \mathbb E[X_s]$?

Yes because $\mathbb E[X_Y\vert Y=s]=\mathbb E[X_s\vert Y=s]$ and $X_s$ and $Y$ are independent.

Thanks! Can you comment on the identity given? Why does it hold. Due to independence?

The equality I wrote is not due to independence. It is just that $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)\vert Y=y]=\mathbb E[f(X,y)\vert Y=y]$. You can deduce that from the definition of conditional expectation.

The interesting thing about this problem is whether $X_Y$ is a random variable.
